# What is the repository language percentage bar in Gitlab actually measuring?

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab has this percentage bar for repositories:

[image: Gitlab percentage bar]

Does this measure the percentage of files in the repository using that language? Or perhaps the number of lines of a particular language in the repository? I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it shows the percentage of files in the repository using that language.

GitHub uses [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) which seems to count language percentages on byte size of the code not on Lines of Code.

GitLab used to use linguist too, but [it looks like they have switched](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/issues/2571) to [go-enry](https://github.com/go-enry/go-enry) which works the same way:

> enry guesses a programming language using a sequence of matching
> strategies that are applied progressively to narrow down the possible
> options. Each strategy varies on the type of input data that it needs
> to make a decision: file name, extension, the first line of the file,
> the full content of the file, etc.